# Error in installing mlabwrap in Windows

Tags: python, mlabwrap

I tried to install mlabwrap in Windows by following the steps in [this article](http://obasic.net/how-to-install-mlabwrap-on-windows). After I completed all steps, when I typed `from mlabwrap import mlab` in Python, I got the following error:

```
>>> from mlabwrap import mlab

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from mlabwrap import mlab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mlabwrap.py", line 188, in <module>
    import mlabraw
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I set all my path and environment variables according to the above link. So why do I get this error? The last step I performed is from mlabwrap directory, I typed

```
python setup.py install
```

Is there any other step after this? I saw it generates `mlabwrap.py` in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this error by putting c:/Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/R2009b/bin/win32 on the PATH so mlabraw could find the Matlab DLLs.  I assume this error means mlabraw could not be loaded because it depends on a DLL that could not be found.